# How do you get Entity Framework to retrieve Nested Objects on Find/FindAsync from the DbContext on dotnet6.0

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

## Summarization of Problem

### Details about goal

I want to retrieve an object and its nested object members from the database using EFCore and SQLite.

### Expected and Actual Results

Currently, only the basic types are being instantiated properly while the nested objects are left in a default/null state and lists are left empty.
What I expect to happen is that EFCore will make the additional calls and fill my object completely.

### Error Messages

No errors are thrown, just garbage data is returned.

## What I have attempted

1. I have tried to drop the database and rebuild with EFCore in hopes of fixing any minor problems that might have shown up over multiple updates.
2. I also checked the database to make sure there were valid entries to all the nested data that I required.
3. I also tried using raw sql but it would throw an error about something already being referenced before when trying to use table joining.

## Simplified Reproduction

I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation 3.2.0-rc1.2023.4 to get access to ValidateComplexObjects.

### FullName.cs

```
public class FullName
{
    public ulong ID { get; set; }
    
    #region Name

    [Display(
        Name = "First Name", 
        AutoGenerateField = true, 
        AutoGenerateFilter = true, 
        Description = "The first name of a person", 
        GroupName = "Name",
        Order = 2, Prompt = "Enter first name here", 
        ShortName = "FName")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "First name can't be shorted than 3 letters")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [Display(
        Name = "Last Name", 
        AutoGenerateField = true, 
        AutoGenerateFilter = true, 
        Description = "The last name of a person", 
        GroupName = "Name",
        Order = 1, Prompt = "Enter last name here", 
        ShortName = "LName")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Last name can't be shorted than 3 letters")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    [Display(
        Name = "Middle Name", 
        AutoGenerateField = true, 
        AutoGenerateFilter = true, 
        Description = "The middle name of a person", 
        GroupName = "Name",
        Order = 50, Prompt = "Enter middle name here", 
        ShortName = "MName")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Middle name can't be shorted than 3 letters")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string Name => $"{FirstName} {MiddleName} {LastName}";
    #endregion

}
```

### Track.cs

```
// Data on tracks that can be ranned on and how long they are
public record Track(int Id, [Required] string Name, [Required]int distanceInMiles);
```

### Person.cs

```
public class Person{
   public ulong Id {get;set;}
   [ValidateComplexType]  public FullName Name {get; set;}
   [Required] public string Description {get;set;}
   [ValidateComplexType] public List<Track> FriendsName {get;set;}
}
```

### ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<FullName> Names { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

### ViewPeople.razor

```
@page "/Person/View/{id}"
// Project usings
@inject ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext

@if(validId){ @*Blah Blah HTML*@ }
else { "Invalid Id Requested" }

@code {
    Person person;
    
    [Parameter]
    public string id { get; set; }

    bool validId = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        validId = ulong.TryParse(id, out var iId);
        person = await ApplicationDbContext.Persons.FindAsync(iId);
        validId = person is not null;
    }
}
```

### What the table generated from EFCore looks like

#### Name Table

| id | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Wittle | Door |

#### Track Table

id, Name, DistanceInMiles, PersonId

| id | Name | DistanceInMiles | PersonId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Honalulu | 12km | 1 |
| 2 | Honalulu 2 | 1km | x |
| 3 | Honalulu 6 | 4km | 1 |

#### Person Table

id, NameId, Description

| id | NameId | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | "I am not a cadaver" |

#### Expectations

##### What I expect

```
{ 
    Id: 1, 
    Name : 
    { 
        Id: 1, 
        FirstName: "John", 
        MiddleName: "Wittle",
        LastName: "Doe"
     },
     Description: "I am not a cadaver",
     Tracks = [
        {Id: 1, Name: "Honalulu", DistanceInMidles: 12km },
        {Id: 2, Name: "Honalulu 2", DistanceInMidles: 1km },
        {Id: 3, Name: "Honalulu 6", DistanceInMidles: 4km },
     ]
}
```

##### What I Get

```
{ 
    Id: 1, 
    Name : 
    { 
        Id: 0, 
        FirstName: null, 
        MiddleName: null,
        LastName: null
     },
     Description: "I am not a cadaver",
     Tracks = []
}
```

Comment: Then don't use `.Find`, instead compose your query like `.Where(...).Include(...).Single()`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. When I followed MSDN documentation it never told me about those. It always used find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFCore does exactly would you have asked it to do. Consider your 'OnInitializedAsync' in your 'ViewPeople.razor'.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ..
    person = await ApplicationDbContext.Persons.FindAsync(iId);
    ..
}
```

All your are asking EFCore to do, is to return the person record with ID 'iID' - nothing else. In order to include dependent entities you need to explicitly tell EFCore to do so. In your particular case:

```
person = await ApplicationDbContext.Persons
   .Include(x => x.FriendsName);
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == iId);
```

If your Track entity had another dependent entity, .Include-calls could also be chained, e.g.:

```
person = await ApplicationDbContext.Persons
   .Include(x => x.FriendsName);
   .ThenInclude(x => x.DependentEntitiesOfTrack)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == iId);
```